# Use string to get field value of scala class without reflection?

Tags: json, scala

```
case class Foo {
    fieldA: Option[Double],
    fieldB: Option[Double]
}

    val foo = Foo( 
        fieldA = Some(1.0), 
        fieldB = Some(2.0)
)
```

Given the string `"fieldA"`, I want to get the value of `foo.fieldA`, which is `Some(1.0)`. Is it possible to NOT use reflection, since the code is going to be used in production?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "NOT use reflection". You can use `foo.fieldA.get` which returns `1.0`.

Comment: In your example code, `fieldA` is `Some(1.0)` not `Some(2.0)`.

Comment: @jwvh  thanks. updated.

Comment: @Brian When provided with `"fieldA"`, I don't really know it's `foo.fieldA` that I need. So the question is how to get `foo.fieldA` from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the short answer is "no".

A slightly longer answer is that, if you want to retrieve a field from any element, using just a string with the name of that element, then you have to use reflection.

That said, you could write a look-up function, as follows:

```scala
case class Foo(fieldA: Option[Double], fieldB: Option[Double]) {

  //...

  def byFieldName(name: String): Option[Double] = name match {
    case "fieldA" => fieldA
    case "fieldB" => fieldB
  }
}
```

It's a bit manual, but it works. Alternatively, you could implement this function using reflection, caching the result in a `Map[String, Option[Double]]` (assuming all such fields have the same type). That way, you would only get the performance hit once for each looked-up field.

**UPDATE**: I should point out that maybe this isn't what you want in any case. If you need to retrieve field values by name, would the following work for you instead of a `case class` (demonstrated in the *Scala REPL*)?

```scala
scala> type Foo = Map[String, Option[Double]]
defined type alias Foo

scala> val foo: Foo = Map("fieldA" -> Some(1.0), "fieldB" -> Some(2.0))
foo: Foo = Map(fieldA -> Some(1.0), fieldB -> Some(2.0))

scala> foo("fieldA")
res0: Option[Double] = Some(1.0)
```

That is, could you use a `Map` data structure to lookup labeled values?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inspiration. I was thinking about converting the `case class` to `Map`, but I guess the "manual solution" would work best. Thank you!!!! :)